# maximized the trace of $V^T A V$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, computer-science, data-analysis, data-mining

given a symmetric matrix A, of dimension $n \times n $ and an an arbitrary unitary matrix V of dimension $ n \times n$ the the trace of $V^T A V$ is an orthogonal basis of the eigenspace associated with the largest eigenvalues.\

In particular, it is achieved for the eigenbasis itself: if eigenvalues are labeled decreasingly
and $ u_1,...,u_d$ are eigenvectors associated with the first d eigenvalues $\lambda_1, ...   ,\lambda_d$ and $U=[u_1,....,u_d]$ with $U^T U=I$, then
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\max\limits_{V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}} \operatorname{Tr}\left[V^{T} A V\right]=\operatorname{Tr}\left[U^{T} A U\right]=\lambda_{1}+\cdots+\lambda_{d} \\
V^{T} V=I
\end{array}\right.
$$

The proof is an immediate consequence of the courant-Fisher characterization. But i don't see how we suppose to use it?

Comment: They don't make use of the Courant-Fischer characterization, but some proofs can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3547462/81360) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3184606/81360).

Comment: more proofs here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3637453/maximize-mathrmtrqtcq-subject-to-qtq-i/

Comment: @BenGrossmann . In the article, the authors said " While this result is seldom explicitly stated on its own in standard textbooks, it is an immediate consequence of the Courant-Fisher characterization''.