# given a symmetric matrix A, of dimension n*n and an arbitrary unitary matrix V of dimension n*d . Maximize the trace of $V^T A V$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, data-analysis, data-mining

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\max _{V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}} \operatorname{Tr}\left[V^{T} A V\right]=\lambda_{1}+\cdots+\lambda_{d} \\
V^{T} V=I
\end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: You've asked this [question before](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4076166/81360) and got some responses in the comments. If you want a different response, say something different. For instance, is there something not addressed by these comments that you are looking for?

Comment: By the way, this is not how the term "unitary" is typically used.